# Python:Update list of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a list of tuples like this:

list =   [(1, 'q'), (2, 'w'), (3, 'e'), (4, 'r')]

and i am trying to create a update function update(item,num) which search the item in the list and then change the num.

for example if i use update(w,6) the result would be

```
list =   [(1, 'q'), (6, 'w'), (3, 'e'), (4, 'r')]
```

i tried this code but i had error

```
if item in heap:
        heap.remove(item)
        Pushheap(item,num)
    else:
        Pushheap(item,num)
```

Pushheap is a function that push tuples in the heap
any ideas?

Comment: you can't assign a value in a tuple, so you'll have to replace the tuple entirely

Comment: Not entirely clear what you want the function to do. An example as well as the things you've tried would be helpful

Comment: You cannot. tuples are immutable. You can however, remove tuples from the list, and replace them to work around this. But may i ask why your using tuple if you'll be needing to change the values of them?

Comment: BTW, you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name because that shadows the built-in `list` type, and that can lead to mysterious bugs.

Comment: That is fine as long as 'w' is only present in just one tuple. If it's present in multiple tuples, do you want all of them to be updated?

Comment: the problem is that i cant search in list if i now only one part of tuple.So i cant find where in the list is

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should post a solution that you have or have tried and if you want an opinion whether it can be done better.

Comment: i want to update only the first one

Comment: You don't need to know both items in a tuple to search for it. But as brianpck suggests, a dictionary may be a more suitable data structure than a list, unless you need to preserve the order of your tuples (because a dictionary isn't ordered) or if multiple tuples have the same letter (because keys in a dict must be unique).

Comment: i care about the order because i want to have a heap

Comment: Ok. Did you know that Python has a [heapq](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html) module? The [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module may also be of interest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply scan through the list looking for a tuple with the desired letter and replace the whole tuple (you can't modify tuples), breaking out of the loop when you've found the required item. Eg,

```
lst = [(1, 'q'), (2, 'w'), (3, 'e'), (4, 'r')]

def update(item, num):
    for i, t in enumerate(lst):
        if t[1] == item:
            lst[i] = num, item
            break

update('w', 6)
print(lst)
```

**output**

```
[(1, 'q'), (6, 'w'), (3, 'e'), (4, 'r')]
```

However, you should seriously consider using a dictionary instead of a list of tuples. Searching a dictionary is much more efficient than doing a linear scan over a list.

Comment: @PM_2Ring Capturing index through `enumerate` was enlightening. +1

Comment: @Rakesh_K `enumerate` is a very useful function. Not only does it lead to clean compact code, it's faster than looping over a `range` of the indices and indexing into the list (or other ordered collection). BTW, it can take an additional `start` arg in case you want to start counting from some number other than zero.

Answer (score 3):

As noted in the comments, you are using an immutable data structure for data items that you are attempting to change. Without further context, it looks like you want a dictionary, not a list of tuples, and it also looks like you want the second item in the tuple (the letter) to be the key, since you are planning on modifying the number.

Using these assumptions, I recommend converting the list of tuples to a dictionary and then using normal dictionary assignment. This also assumes that *order* is not important (if it is, you can use an `OrderedDict`) and that the same letter does not appear twice (if it does, only the last number will be in the dict).

```
>>> lst =  [(1, 'q'), (2, 'w'), (3, 'e'), (4, 'r')]
>>> item_dict = dict(i[::-1] for i in lst)
>>> item_dict
{'q': 1, 'r': 4, 'e': 3, 'w': 2}
>>> item_dict['w'] = 6
>>> item_dict
{'q': 1, 'r': 4, 'e': 3, 'w': 6}
```

Answer (score 1):

Tuples are an immutable object. Which means once they're created, you can't go changing there contents.

You can, work around this however, by replaceing the tuple you want to change. Possibly something such as this:

```
def change_item_in_list(lst, item, num):
    for pos, tup in enumerate(lst):
        if tup[1] == item:
            lst[pos] = (num, item)
            return

l = [(1, 'q'), (2, 'w'), (3, 'e'), (4, 'r')]
print(l)
change_item_in_list(l, 'w', 6)
print(l)
```

But as @brianpck has already said, you probably want a (ordered)-dictionary instead of a list of tuples.